# Using relative import without from

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, python-import

Instead of:

```
from .model import Foo, Bar
```

I would like to:

```
import .model
```

This raises a syntax error. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything following an `import` keyword must be a valid Python name as it will be added to your scope under that same name.

Instead, do the following.

```
from . import model
```

Comment: I wish there was a way to avoid `Foo = model.Foo`, `Bar = model.Bar` that would come after for an equivalent effect as `from ... import` (which is not as nice as it makes you type `Foo` and `Bar` twice.